# Edge-to-edge Image + Text in MailChimp

Tags: formatting, e-mail, mailchimp

I'm creating an email in MailChimp using content blocks. (I'll be happy to use another method, but that seems to be the most convenient method at the outset.)

Within the `Image` content block, there is a `Settings` option for Edge-to-Edge margin formatting. I'd like to set the same option within an `Image + Text` content block, but there doesn't seem to be such an option.

I can also create an `HTML` content block, but that's obviously less than ideal because 1. I can't create the content block responsive without much more work than I'd like to put in, and 2. It's frankly much easier to use the pre-designed content blocks than to create a bespoke one.

Is anyone familiar with how to do this in the `Image + Text` content block in MailChimp?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Code" block. Place your text inside the following div.

```
<div class="mcnTextContent" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 150%;"> </div>
```

For the image, you can either place an "Image Block" above or below, or you can add an image tag inside the "Code" block.